# I can't override bootstrap css in rails with my custom css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to rails and was following this tutorial https://launchschool.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1#css_preprocessors when I got to the part of adding bootstrap by adding

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

at the very bottom of `application.css.sass` it all worked perfectly fine. However, I had a line of code

`html, body{background:#000;color:#FFF;}`

that wasn't being respected. After looking around, I realized that it's because of my application file:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require custom
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

I understand that since "bootstrap" is at the very bottom, that is the css that the website uses, however, if I move it to the top or in any other spot, I get an error page. Is there another way for me to import bootstrap or for me to override the page?

Comment: If you're using the **.sass** syntax then `html, body { background:#000;color:#FFF; }` isn't valid for one. You can also refer to the [Bootstrap-SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails) Docs for Ruby implementations.

Comment: I wanted to ask you if you have an update. Thanks Fabrizio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote https://github.com/rails/sprockets#the-require_self-directive

> The require_self Directive
>
> **require_self** tells Sprockets to insert the body **of the current source file** **before any subsequent require directives**.

This means that if your require_self and then import bootstrap, as CSS stands for *cascade style sheets*, the last style will always be applied plus rules of **css specificity**.
Read about css specificity at the following link
http://cssspecificity.com/

You can try setting !important to test if the problem is solved. An alternative would be including as suggested your css or scss code in a separate file:

```
*= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require custom
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
@import "my-css-style"
```

If you still have doubts, check how the application.css.scss is loaded at localhost:3000/assets/application.css.scss to see how the different stylesheets are loaded in one file, then also work with debug on chrome/firefox, disable all the styles until you figure out which one is overriding.

[image]